# Puppet 3 break function

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet server 3.8 and I would like to use conditional statement and when this statement is true that exit or break function that is do nothing
 I've tried like this

```
class puppet {

 if $puppet_conf == 'default' {
  break()
 }
}
```

but I got error

```
 Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function break at /etc/puppet/modules/puppet/manifests/init.pp:4 on node
```

anyone knows how can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `break()` should do?

Comment: In my opinion break() should basically exit if condition without any consequence, that is do nothing if condition is fulfilled.

Comment: You mean exit the class entirely without applying anything? This is a declarative language so that would require a different kind of coding logic.

Comment: Yes, exit class if condition is fulfilled.

Comment: You basically would have to wrap the entire class inside the conditional. This would be either the `include/declare/require/contain`, or the contents of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The break function was only added in Puppet 4.8, so it won't work in 3.8

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/function.html#break

However, what are you trying to achieve? The `break()` function simply quits the logic block, so that `if` statement would doesn't really have a point.

If you want to fail the Puppet run if that variable is present, you can just do

```
if $puppet_conf == 'default' {
  fail('Error message')
}
```

Comment: This aligns with my best guess, but we will have to wait for the asker to explain what he thinks `break()` should do.

Comment: When I implement this code, I get error during execution of "puppet agent -t"